# add capabilitie to customer based on product categorie

Tags: php, woocommerce, categories, product, role

My website is using wordpress, "the events calendar" plugin and "woocommerce" and I manage roles and capabilities with "Advanced Access Manager" plugin.

I try to add a function that will add a capability to the role of a buyer based on the product category they have just bought.

So I try to get the product *(just bought)* or the event category from the user ID, but something is going wrong and it's almost impossible to test step by step, because the process need to be finish to let the function work.

Here is the code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'custom_process_order', 10, 1);

function custom_process_order($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $myuser_id = (int)$order->user_id;
    $user_info = get_userdata($myuser_id);
    $items = $order->get_items();

    // need to test that :

    $beta= str_replace(
        ':',
        '',
        tribe_get_event_categories($event->ID, array(
            'echo'         => false,
            'label'        => '',
            ' label_before' => '',
            'label_after'  => '',
            'wrap_before'  => '',
            'wrap_after'   => '',
    )));
    $beta = strip_tags($beta);

    foreach ($items as $item) {

        //check if user already have capabilitie
        if ( ! user_can( $user_id, $capability )){

            //add capability to specific user
            $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
            $user->add_cap( $beta );
        }
    }
    return $order_id;
}
```

So for example a customer buy a product with the category "course_paris_night" and so it should have the role capability "course_paris_night". With that capability this customer will access tutorial on the same category by example.

Thanks for any help on the code or on the way to test it ! (need to learn !)

SO !!! 24 April...few days later :

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'custom_process_order', 10, 1);

function custom_process_order($order_id) {
    global $current_user;
    global $wp_roles;

    $order = new WC_Order($item->ID);

    $order->populate($item);        
    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ($items as $key => $item2 ) :
        $event_id_in_product = absint($item2['product_id']);
    endforeach;

    // trouve la catégorie du produit acheté par le stagiaire
    // Get all terms associated with post in woocommerce's taxonomy 'product_cat'
    $terms = get_the_terms( $event_id_in_product, 'product_cat' );

    //Get an array of their IDs
    $term_ids = wp_list_pluck($terms,'term_id');

    //Get array of parents - 0 is not a parent
    $parents = array_filter(wp_list_pluck($terms,'parent'));

    //Get array of IDs of terms which are not parents.
    $term_ids_not_parents = array_diff($term_ids, $parents);

    //Get corresponding term objects.
    $terms_not_parents = array_intersect_key($terms, $term_ids_not_parents);

    //Extract the name of the category from the array and post it.
    foreach($terms_not_parents as $term_not_parent){
        $beta = $term_not_parent->name;

        $alpha = strip_tags($beta);
        $alpha = trim(strip_tags($alpha));
        $alpha = str_replace(' - ',' ',$alpha);
        $alpha = strtolower($alpha);


        $all_roles = $wp_roles->roles;
        $user = new WP_User( $current_user->ID );
        $result = $user->add_role($alpha);

        return $order_id;
    }
}
```

But I don't get any good results. So testing again here it is what I get has user info:

```
WP_User Object
(
[data] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] => 50
        [user_login] => buyer.new
        [user_pass] => $P$BKlx7.CzfvnLL43EZaZdmo84shZQo41
        [user_nicename] => buyer-new
        [user_email] => mymail@mysite.com
        [user_url] => 
        [user_registered] => 2016-04-23 22:05:27
        [user_activation_key] => 
        [user_status] => 0
        [display_name] => New
    )

[ID] => 50
[caps] => Array
    (
        [mycourse saint-malo intermédiaire] => 1
        [mycourse paris avancé] => 1
    )

[cap_key] => lep_capabilities
[roles] => Array
    (
        [0] => mycourse saint-malo intermédiaire
    )

[allcaps] => Array
    (
        [read] => 1
        [level_0] => 1
        [read_private_tribe_organizers] => 1
        [mycourse saint-malo intermédiaire] => 1
        [mycourse paris avancé] => 1
    )

[filter] => 
)
```

Normaly has my user was buying two new course under category "mycourse saint-malo intermédiaire" and "mycourse paris avancé" I should have under "[roles] => Array" the two new roles ...but has you can see it's not.

My code is adding the two new role into [caps] and [allcaps] but not into [roles] !!!!

I am sure I am very close. Any idea ?

//UPDATE//

Sorry !!! I forgot some important steps and I finally discover what was not working in my test code (I Test it directly on a page not in a function...will do that tomorrow...here it's 2.3 am)

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'custom_process_order', 10, 1);

function custom_process_order($order_id) {
    global $current_user;
    global $wp_roles;

    $all_orders = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
        //'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        //'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
    'post_status' => 'completed',
    ) );

    $args = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
    'post_status' => 'completed',
    ) );

if( ! empty($args)){
foreach($args as $item) {
    setup_postdata( $item );

 $order = new WC_Order($item->ID);

$order->populate($item);        
$items = $order->get_items();

foreach ($items as $key => $item2 ) :
    $event_id_in_product = absint($item2['product_id']);
    endforeach;

      //trouve la catégorie du produit acheté par le stagiaire
    //Get all terms associated with post in woocommerce's taxonomy 'product_cat'
    $terms = get_the_terms( $event_id_in_product, 'product_cat' );

    //Get an array of their IDs
    $term_ids = wp_list_pluck($terms,'term_id');

    //Get array of parents - 0 is not a parent
    $parents = array_filter(wp_list_pluck($terms,'parent'));

    //Get array of IDs of terms which are not parents.
    $term_ids_not_parents = array_diff($term_ids, $parents);

    //Get corresponding term objects.
    $terms_not_parents = array_intersect_key($terms, $term_ids_not_parents);

    //Extract the name of the category from the array and post it.
    foreach($terms_not_parents as $term_not_parent){
        $beta = $term_not_parent->name;

    $alpha = strip_tags($beta);
    $alpha = trim(strip_tags($alpha));
    $alpha = str_replace(' - ',' ',$alpha);
    $alpha = str_replace('Stage','stagiaire',$alpha);
    $alpha = strtolower($alpha);


$all_roles = $wp_roles->roles;
    $user = new WP_User( $current_user->ID );
    $result = $user->add_role($alpha, $alpha, array($alpha =>true,)); // Array was missing in previous version !

return $order_id;
}
}
}
```

Comment: This isn't easy for me to follow exactly what you're asking, to be honest with you

Comment: this is what I'm understanding. After a customer completes their order, you would like to create a login account for them and have their role based upon the category of the product purchased. And that role directly relates to a tutorial category that has the same name.

Comment: Let say you want to restrict your tutorial to the people who buy your course but you want them to access only the tutorial corresponding to the category of the product they buy: ex: I buy a course "basic" so I can access to "basic" tutorial and not "advanced" ones. (using a plugin to manage access based on user role AND capabilities) So a customer is registred as "customer role" and have no access to "basic tutorial" because for that he needs "basic" in is capabilitie.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution and it's working great under my test page but...

```
// Retrieve customer order
$blc_args = get_posts( array('numberposts' => -1,'meta_key'    =>'_customer_user','meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),'post_type'   => 'shop_order','post_status' => 'completed',) );

if( ! empty($blc_args)){
foreach($blc_args as $blc_item) {
    setup_postdata( $item );

    $blc_order = new WC_Order($blc_item->ID);

    $blc_order->populate($blc_item);

    $blc_items = $blc_order->get_items();

    foreach ($blc_items as $blc_key => $blc_item2 ) :
    //print_r($item2);
    $event_id_in_product = absint($blc_item2['product_id']);

    //Get all terms associated with post in woocommerce's taxonomy 'product_cat'
    $blc_terms = get_the_terms( $event_id_in_product, 'product_cat' );

    //echo"</br>";
    //echo "Event ID embed in product bought : " . $event_id_in_product;
    //echo"</br>";

    //Get an array of their IDs
    $blc_term_ids = wp_list_pluck($blc_terms,'term_id');

    //Get array of parents - 0 is not a parent
    $blc_parents = array_filter(wp_list_pluck($blc_terms,'parent'));

    //Get array of IDs of terms which are not parents.
    $blc_term_ids_not_parents = array_diff($blc_term_ids, $blc_parents);

    //Get corresponding term objects.
    $blc_terms_not_parents = array_intersect_key($blc_terms, $blc_term_ids_not_parents);

    //Extract the name of the category from the array and post it.
    foreach($blc_terms_not_parents as $blc_term_not_parent){
        $blc_start = $blc_term_not_parent->name;
    }

    if(preg_match("/(Ultérieure|cadeau)/i", $blc_start)){

    }else{
        $beta = utf8_decode($blc_start);
        $beta = trim(strip_tags($beta));
        $beta_without_accent = strtr($beta, utf8_decode('àáâãäçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöùúûüýÿÀÁÂÃÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝ'), 'aaaaaceeeeiiiinooooouuuuyyAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOUUUUY');
        $beta_with_minuscule = strtolower($beta_without_accent);
        $beta_with_minuscule = str_replace('balade - ','stagiaire_',$beta_with_minuscule);
        $beta_with_underscore = str_replace(' - ', '_', $beta_with_minuscule);
        $beta_stagiaire = str_replace('stage','stagiaire',$beta_with_underscore);

        global $current_user;

        $user = new WP_User( $current_user->ID );
        $user->add_role($beta_stagiaire);
    }
    endforeach;
}
}
```

...yes...but ! when editing and parsing in my functions under my child theme it doesn't do it. Sometimes it seems to process it because the last echo appear (sometimes) and send me back the right "role to create".

Here it is the same code but build to be include in function.php:

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'custom_process_order', 10, 1);

function custom_process_order($order_id) {
    global $current_user;

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();

//      echo"</br>";
//      echo "Product ID : " . ($order->id);

    //$order->populate($item);
     //print_r($order);

    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ($items as $key => $item2 ) :
    //print_r($item2);
    $event_id_in_product = absint($item2['product_id']);

    //Get all terms associated with post in woocommerce's taxonomy 'product_cat'
    $terms = get_the_terms( $event_id_in_product, 'product_cat' );

    //echo"</br>";
    //echo "Event ID embed in product bought : " . $event_id_in_product;
    //echo"</br>";

    //Get an array of their IDs
    $term_ids = wp_list_pluck($terms,'term_id');

    //Get array of parents - 0 is not a parent
    $parents = array_filter(wp_list_pluck($terms,'parent'));

    //Get array of IDs of terms which are not parents.
    $term_ids_not_parents = array_diff($term_ids, $parents);

    //Get corresponding term objects.
    $terms_not_parents = array_intersect_key($terms, $term_ids_not_parents);

    //Extract the name of the category from the array and post it.
    foreach($terms_not_parents as $term_not_parent){
        $start = $term_not_parent->name;            
    }

    //echo"</br>";
    //echo "Product Category : " . $start;
    //echo"</br>";

    if(preg_match("/(Ultérieure|cadeau)/i", $start)){
//echo"</br>";
    //echo "Don't add that Product Category : " . $start;
    //echo"</br>";
    }else{
    $beta = utf8_decode($start);
    $beta = trim(strip_tags($beta));
    $beta_without_accent = strtr($beta, utf8_decode('àáâãäçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöùúûüýÿÀÁÂÃÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝ'), 'aaaaaceeeeiiiinooooouuuuyyAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOUUUUY');
    $beta_with_minuscule = strtolower($beta_without_accent);
    $beta_with_minuscule = str_replace('balade - ','stagiaire_',$beta_with_minuscule);
    $beta_with_underscore = str_replace(' - ', '_', $beta_with_minuscule);
    $beta_stagiaire = str_replace('stage','stagiaire',$beta_with_underscore);

    echo"</br>";
    echo "Role to create : " . $beta_stagiaire;
    echo"</br>";

    $user = new WP_User( $current_user->ID );

    $user->add_role($beta_stagiaire);
    }
    endforeach;


return $order_id;
 }
```

And has you can imagine to test it it's not that easy because I have to do the payment process.

Any error I let somewhere ? I don't see it.

Comment: WORKING SOLUTION : ...it doesn't work in a function on my child theme so I put it in a custom "thankyou.php" in my child theme and it is working 100% now. If you want to use it for your app just custom the way i handle role and category name. The code is not a clean code and if anybody find a way to clean it and make it work as function ...let me know.

Comment: Don't forget to save your php as UTF8 NO BOM ;-)